# Is push notification sent through a cloud code considered as an additional API call?

Tags: android, parse-platform

Official documentation advises not to use client push notification. Instead cloud push notifications should be used. But does that count as an API call?

**CODE:**

```
// WRONG WAY TO SEND PUSH - INSECURE!
ParseQuery pushQuery = ParseInstallation.getQuery();
pushQuery.whereEqualTo("user", userObject);
ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
String message = currentUser.getString("name") + " says Hi!";

ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
push.setQuery(pushQuery); // Set our Installation query
push.setMessage(message);
push.sendInBackground();
```

**vs (cloud version + missing cloud code):**

```
HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("recipientId", userObject.getObjectId());
params.put("message", message);
ParseCloud.callFunctionInBackground("sendPushToUser", params, new FunctionCallback<String>() {
   void done(String success, ParseException e) {
       if (e == null) {
          // Push sent successfully
       }
   }
});
```

I mean, if I would have use client push notifications, would that be 1 call per push less? Since `parse.com` is restricting users on call/s, then it is very important to know.

**UPDATE:**
The first option, is not right one, it is client push which performs only 1 API call/request. 
While second one, just asks ParseCloud to do the push for itself. But that means, it is 2 API calls/requests. Because one is performed by Android app to cloud, and then cloud is doing the actual push. But I just wanted to know if it is really like that.

Comment: I believe it does, however you could save the message and perform the push as an `afterSave` function. Then you can have a history stored and get the message sent in a single call.

Comment: Thank you for a comment, but I think you misunderstood.The first option, is not right one, it is client push which performs only 1 API call/request. While second one, just asks ParseCloud to do the push for himself. But that means, it is 2 API calls/requests. Because one is performed by Android app to cloud, and then cloud is doing the actual push. But I just wanted to know if it is really like that.

Comment: I can see what you mean. Must admit I am very much in doubt. Is a bit unfortunate having to double the amount of API requests to create pushes the recommended way.

Comment: Exactly ;/, anyway thanks for the effort. It seems there is no other way.

Comment: After re-visiting their payment plans site, it might not be that big a deal. Previously they had a limit of 1 mil. req/month. Now it looks like it is only req/s that is considered.